# Switch approle on client side

Tags: sql-server

Currently I am working on a project where a winforms application works together with a sql server database. I want the following behavior:
1) User connects before login to database with a db user with low permissions.
2) When the user login the db checks if the user is administrator. If thats true the application role switches to the administrator application role. Else the user login with standard application role.

The problem is that I can't execute the sp_setapprole in a stored procedure on the database and the winforms application needs the password of the administrator application role stored somewhere. Thats not safety for sure. So whats a possible workaround?

Comment: If you can't trust the client, then having it set its own role is no good. You'll have to assign permissions directly on the user executing the application. As in, create logins tied to Windows groups that have the appropriate permissions, then add the users to those groups based on the permissions they should have. If you cannot maintain Windows groups, you can check membership server-side with functions like `SYSTEM_USER`. The important thing is to have a method of identification the client can't simply spoof.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't have windows users or groups.

Comment: How does your WinForms application know what app role to activate? You have *some* form of identifying the user, right? Are you managing your own password database?